# Angularjs Using $http and $cookies in Service

Tags: angularjs, http, cookies

i get an error when i try to use angular-cookie and $http: 
*TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined*

Did i inject it in a wrong way? without ng-cookies everything works fine!

Thx

```
static $inject = ['$rootScope','$http', '$cookies', '$q','$cookieStore','$window'];

constructor(public $scope: ng.IScope, public $window: ng.IWindowService, public $http: ng.IHttpService, private $q: ng.IQService, public $cookieStore: ng.cookies.ICookieStoreService, public $cookies: ng.cookies.ICookiesService) {
}

loginUserOnApi (userData: any) {

    let deferred = this.$q.defer();
    let parameters = {
        username: userData.title,
        password: userData.password
    };

    let config = {
      params: parameters,
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
    };
    let self  = this;

    this.$http.get(this.loginApiUrl , config).then(response => {
        self.status = response.data['ack'];
        self.$cookies.putObject('new-acc-var',response);
        deferred.resolve(response.data);

    }).catch( reason => {
        deferred.reject(reason);
    });

    return deferred.promise;

   }
```

error:

```
index.js:67374 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
at LoginService.loginUserOnApi (index.js:9794)
at LoginUserController.loginUserOverService (index.js:8911)
at fn (eval at compile (index.js:68225), <anonymous>:4:202)
at callback (index.js:80046)
at Scope.$eval (index.js:71116)
at Scope.$apply (index.js:71215)
at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (index.js:80051)
at defaultHandlerWrapper (index.js:56368)
at HTMLFormElement.eventHandler (index.js:56356)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static $inject = ['$rootScope','$http', '$cookies', '$q','$cookieStore','$window'];

constructor(public $scope: ng.IScope, public $window: ng.IWindowService, public $http: ng.IHttpService, private $q: ng.IQService, public $cookieStore: ng.cookies.ICookieStoreService, public $cookies: ng.cookies.ICookiesService) {
}
```

Check - order is incorrect. in $inject http is 2nd, in function - 3rd.